# python how to get all branch combinations of a directory / binary tree? as i march

Tags: python, dictionary, pip, binary, binary-tree

i have a dictionary structure, that i want to get all the combination in order as i march

```
my_data = {
  "my_root": {
      "first_key": {
          "second_key": {
              "bunch": {
                  "bunch1": [
                      "a1",
                      "a2"
                  ],
                  "bunch2": [
                      "b2",
                      "b2"
                  ],
                  "ad": [
                      "ad1"
                  ]
              }
          },
          "another_key": {
              "one": [
                  "1",
                  "2"
              ],
              "two": [
                  "11",
                  "22"
              ]
          }
      }
  }
}
```

i am trying to get

```
["my_root"]
["my_root", "first_key"]
["my_root", "first_key", "second_key"]
["my_root", "first_key", "second_key", "bunch"]
["my_root", "first_key", "second_key", "bunch", "bunch1"]
["my_root", "first_key", "second_key", "bunch", "bunch1", "a1"]
["my_root", "first_key", "second_key", "bunch", "bunch1", "a2"]
["my_root", "first_key", "second_key", "bunch", "bunch2"]
["my_root", "first_key", "second_key", "bunch", "bunch2", "b1"]
["my_root", "first_key", "second_key", "bunch", "bunch2", "b2"]
["my_root", "first_key", "second_key", "bunch", "bunch2", "b2"]
["my_root", "first_key", "second_key", "bunch", "ad",     "ad1"]
["my_root", "first_key", "another_key"]
["my_root", "first_key", "another_key", "one"]
["my_root", "first_key", "another_key", "one", "1"]
["my_root", "first_key", "another_key", "one", "2"]
["my_root", "first_key", "another_key", "two", "11"]
["my_root", "first_key", "another_key", "two", "22"]
```

i have try something like this( thanks Valentin Briukhanov)

```
  def _ordered_components_by_path(indict, pre=None):
      pre = pre[:] if pre else []
      if isinstance(indict, dict):
          for key, value in indict.items():
              if isinstance(value, dict):
                  for d in _ordered_components_by_path(value, pre + [key]):
                      yield d
              elif isinstance(value, list) or isinstance(value, tuple):
                  for v in value:
                      for d in _ordered_components_by_path(v, pre + [key]):
                          yield d
              else:
                  yield pre + [key, value]
      else:
          yield pre + [indict]

  def ordered_components_by_path():
      return _ordered_components_by_path(my_data)
```

but this one just give the all the ends like i am printing below

```
for i in ordered_components_by_path:
  print(i)

['my_root', 'first_key', 'second_key', 'bunch', 'bunch1', 'a1']
['my_root', 'first_key', 'second_key', 'bunch', 'bunch1', 'a2']
['my_root', 'first_key', 'second_key', 'bunch', 'bunch2', 'b2']
['my_root', 'first_key', 'second_key', 'bunch', 'bunch2', 'b2']
['my_root', 'first_key', 'second_key', 'bunch', 'ad', 'ad1']
['my_root', 'first_key', 'another_key', 'one', '1']
['my_root', 'first_key', 'another_key', 'one', '2']
['my_root', 'first_key', 'another_key', 'two', '11']
['my_root', 'first_key', 'another_key', 'two', '22']
```

is there a proper way to do achieve or a library?   thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
def get_path(d, curr_path):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            yield curr_path + [k]
            yield from get_path(v, curr_path + [k])
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for v in d:
            yield from get_path(v, curr_path)
    else:
        yield curr_path + [d]


for p in get_path(my_data, []):
    print(p)
```

Prints:

```
['my_root']
['my_root', 'first_key']
['my_root', 'first_key', 'second_key']
['my_root', 'first_key', 'second_key', 'bunch']
['my_root', 'first_key', 'second_key', 'bunch', 'bunch1']
['my_root', 'first_key', 'second_key', 'bunch', 'bunch1', 'a1']
['my_root', 'first_key', 'second_key', 'bunch', 'bunch1', 'a2']
['my_root', 'first_key', 'second_key', 'bunch', 'bunch2']
['my_root', 'first_key', 'second_key', 'bunch', 'bunch2', 'b2']
['my_root', 'first_key', 'second_key', 'bunch', 'bunch2', 'b2']
['my_root', 'first_key', 'second_key', 'bunch', 'ad']
['my_root', 'first_key', 'second_key', 'bunch', 'ad', 'ad1']
['my_root', 'first_key', 'another_key']
['my_root', 'first_key', 'another_key', 'one']
['my_root', 'first_key', 'another_key', 'one', '1']
['my_root', 'first_key', 'another_key', 'one', '2']
['my_root', 'first_key', 'another_key', 'two']
['my_root', 'first_key', 'another_key', 'two', '11']
['my_root', 'first_key', 'another_key', 'two', '22']
```